# I can't hear any sound from my Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: audio, pi-4, speakers

I can't hear any sounds from my Pi 4. I tried all speaker tests, I've changed my sound output to HDMI1 which I use, and tried all suggestions. The sound just disappeared, without any warning at all. I don't understand what happened. Anyone has that same problem? And any solutions?

Comment: Did the sound ever work? Any reason you can’t just re-flash your sd card?

Comment: If you already tried all suggestions then we also cannot help. Your Raspberry Pi must be broken.

Comment: Even with the tests in https://www.tinkerboy.xyz/raspberry-pi-test-sound-output/ you did not hear a thing? I would try at least to insert in AV port an audio jack and perform the tests on that link

Comment: Also, I was able to hear sounds of downloaded files but not in Chromium, then I found this https://askubuntu.com/questions/284202/chromium-doesnt-play-sound and it solved the issue ;)

Comment: @CoderMike whats an sd card?

Comment: @RCaetano I tried the first one- no sound. Second one- no sound from downloaded files either.

Comment: The micro sd card - the memory card in the side of the Pi that contains the operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out that it was all a misunderstanding and that the sound was controlled by another device. All I had to do was turn up the knob. Can someone tell me how to close this?

Comment: Just click on the check mark next to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this script? I found it somewhere on the here, but it's been a long time and I don't remember where it is. I had this problem too, you should just need to execute this once.

```bsh
sudo modprobe snd_bcmm2835
```